URL to show account chooser for Microsoft
Is there a URL to go to for forcing account selection if you're authenticated with Microsoft?
For example google https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser.
If the user has a single account, I am basically locking him into using just that one after the first login, since the flow is not showing the prompt to choose/switch the account.
I have Microsoft (multi-tenant) as an IDP in Cognito, so using the direct oAuth authorize with prompt is not an option.

Can you post your code where you  call the oauth in your front end website?

It's the standard OAuth with Cognito. But for selecting the account, Cognito doesn't have the option for prompt, so I needed a way to go directly to a URL of google/microsoft to switch accounts / logout.
